# Is a latency between 1 and 2 seconds normal for Google Cloud Endpoints and App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm new to Google Cloud. I followed this tutorial to create a simple API with Google Cloud Endpoints and App Engine, using Cloud Endpoints Frameworks for Java 8:

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java

The tutorial was easy enough to follow, but I'm not happy with the performance of my API. The latency for a simple request is consistently between 1 and 2 seconds, which seems unacceptable for production use. I'm not taking into consideration the first request, as that takes over 10 seconds when my App Engine instance is not loaded.

The URL I'm testing is "_ah/api/echo/v1/echo", which code wise is super simple.

Am I missing something? Is this expected behavior latency wise?

Edit: That behaviour was with a Sao Paulo instance. I now changed to a us-central and a us-east1 instance, and Endpoints is still under performing. I've been doing some other tests though.

When I deploy my API directly to App Engine, without using Endpoints, I get consistent 300ms times from Argentina. When I deploy it with Endpoints, I get times that fluctuate between 500ms to 1.5 seconds. It's not stable at all, and it's bad all around. However, when I test the same thing from within the US, I get times around 50ms for either case. Endpoints don't seem to be a problem there.

Any ideas why I could be having these issues with Endpoints from Argentina?